# Javascript Check if Checkbox is checked inside a table

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript , I've lot of checkboxes and recently I decided  to put those inside a table which will look it more prettier ,( one question per check box inside a table cell ).

I'm working on a code which can check if on a specific cell , particular question / checkbox is check or not. And do something if that is checked .

Here is the sample HTML code :-

```
<tr id ="row2">
    <td><div>Disable Auto Save  : <input type="checkbox" name="disautosave" value="disableauto" id = "disableauto"></div></td>
    <td><div>Enable Stack Monitoring  : <input type="checkbox" name="stackmon" value="enablestackmon" id = "enablestackmon"></div></td>
    <td>3</td>
```

And here is the Javascript code , if I use the alert here , it just pop up and alert with "Disable Auto Save :"  which is the content of the cell

```
var Row = document.getElementById("row2");
var Cells = Row.getElementsByTagName("td");
alert(Cells[0].innerText);
```

However , I was looking for the checkbox value , i.e. to check if checkbox on that given cell is checked or not. I tried the below code ...but its not working.

```
if (Cells[0].checked){
    alert("Checked");
    //alert(Cells[1].innerText);
}
```

Comment: You should put that in a snippet or fiddle.

Comment: Got the answer while playing .....Here                                                                  if (document.getElementById("row2").getElementsByTagName("td")[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked==true)
 {
 
 alert ("Hola");
 
 }

Answer (score 3):

`Cells` in your code refers to a bunch of `td` tags , there's no `checked` property on them

use `var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("row2 input[type=checkbox]")` to get all your checkboxes and then use `checked` on them individually, like :
`checkboxes[0].checked` and so on

Comment: In the cells , am using td tags to put the table data for that row. If you look it got checkbox with id , name & value.   Not sure if that makes sense , but if I dont put that checkbox inside the table. I can easy access if that is checked using below code , which is working :            var vDisauto = (document.getElementById("disableauto").checked);          Later I check this with a if sttement to match if this is true ,,,do this etc logic

Answer (score 0):

Answer taken from the question:

> Got the answer while trying and playing with it
>
> ```
> if (document.getElementById("row2").getElementsByTagName("td")[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked==true)
>  {
>
>  alert ("Hola");
>
>  }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

```
var chk = tableRows[x].cells[5].firstChild; 
// converts from table cell to <input> i get inside of <td> an <input>
```